# Get records with max time inserted MySQL results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have some data row in my table.

I want to select the Age which occurs the most.

```
Person | Group | Age
---
Bob  | 1     | 32  
Jill | 1     | 32  
Shawn| 1     | 42  
Jake | 2     | 29  
Paul | 2     | 36  
Laura| 2     | 39
```

Desired set:

The age that appears the most is 32.

Comment: Maximum time what? Group, Age or Person?

Comment: max time inserted age is 32 @SantoshJagtap

Comment: Without a column that has time value, this is not possible

Comment: Check out the query in answer below

Comment: Note that GROUP is a reserved word.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following query

```
select Person, count(*) as c FROM tableName GROUP BY Age
```

You can add the limit 1 to get the only only record and order by to get the maximum or minimum age. Use following query

```
select Person, count(*) as c,Age FROM profile GROUP BY Age ORDER BY c desc LIMIT 0,1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
SELECT Person,Group,Age,MAX(field_name)  
FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

After grouping the values you can select the top 1 as below : This would select 32 as answer

```
SELECT        TOP (1) Age
FROM            tablename
GROUP BY age
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT age FROM my_table GROUP BY age ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1;`

Fairly obviously, in the case of a tie, this result will be misleading.